# How to get the green dot to turn on for slack user from API POST to users.setPresence?

Tags: slack, slack-api

I'm calling:

https://api.slack.com/methods/users.setPresence

with `presence=auto` and get back a 200 ok but the green light for the user does not turn on.

[image]

I can post messages as these test users but they appear offline.

Answer (score 0):

Oh I think I see how:

```
A user can have one of two possible presence values, active or away. A user is active if they have at least one client connected to Slack, and they are not marked as "away". There are two ways a user can be marked as away: automatic and manual.

presence_change event behavior will change on November 15, 2017. Subscriptions will become mandatory. See below.
Automatic Away

The Slack message servers will automatically detect activity in the client. After 10 minutes with no activity, the user is automatically marked as away. There is some additional nuance to that dependent on the client, explained in detail in our Help Center.
```

`A user is active if they have at least one client connected to Slack`

So there is no way with the API, not with the old RTM, not with socket mode, they just don't allow it. The only way is with cookie auth. You would have to run like a headless-chrome or phantomjs and login as the user. Or just login in a normal browser and copy over the cookies.

It works with:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
import time

options = Options()
options.profile = '/path/to/profile/jenny'
options.add_argument('-headless')
browser = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)
browser.get('https://app.slack.com/client')
time.sleep(26)
browser.quit()
```

And you run

```
/Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS/firefox --profilemanager
```

to make /path/to/profile/jenny and then login as her just once. Repeat for other profiles. I have jenny and fred.