# What is slack websocket payload after you receive Hello message?

Tags: slack, slack-api

I'm doing everything in here:

https://api.slack.com/apis/connections/socket

I get my:

```
{"type":"hello","num_connections":1,"debug_info":{"host":"applink-2","build_number":36,"approximate_connection_time":18060},"connection_info":{"app_id":"A05GWDCG6GY"}}
```

hello message on the web socket connection. Then I want to use that connection not to receive events, but to post as a specific user with a user token.

I've tried various payloads like:

```
  message := map[string]string{}
  message["type"] = "message"
  message["channel"] = channel
  message["app_id"] = s.AppId
  message["user_id"] = user
  message["text"] = "test123"
  message["token"] = token
  asBytes, _ = json.Marshal(message)
```

but there doesn't seem to be any docs on how to send a message as a user over web sockets or set their presence. My goal being:

[How to get the green dot to turn on for slack user from API POST to users.setPresence?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76655921/how-to-get-the-green-dot-to-turn-on-for-slack-user-from-api-post-to-users-setpre)

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do this with their Socket Mode system. You can receive events from the web socket connections, but you cannot post as a user or set the user to online. The only way to do this would be cookie auth and actually run a browser with the user logged in.